# Django custom template tags to remove specific URL query strings

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to create a simple tag for a django template which removes a specified URL query string. It's purpose is to remove some applied filtering, ie remove saved=1 from http://localhost/?saved=1&source=news&week=5

I have created a custom tag:

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def defilter(context, *args):
    query = context['request'].GET.copy()
    for key in args:
        if key in query.keys():
            query.pop(key)
    return query.urlencode()
```

I have then created a link in a django template  which recontructs the url get paramters but removes the specified key:

```
<a href="{% url 'articles' %}?{% defilter saved %}">Remove Saved</a>
```

Any ideas why this isn't working the way I expect? I get no errors, it just doesn't remove the specified key.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question for posterity. I ended up changing from kwargs to a single arg.

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def defilter(context, field):
    query = context['request'].GET.copy()
    if query.get(field):
        query.pop(field)
    return query.urlencode()
```

Works for what I need.